# Python No module named 'TikTok Api'

Tags: python, api

Im trying to figure out where the problem is.

When I run the code, I got an error "Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\user\IdeaProjects\tiktokAnalyse.idea\main\main.py", line 2, in 
import TikTokApi
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'TikTokApi' "

Ive installed "pip install TiKTokApi" and imported with
"`from TikTokApi import TikTokApi`"

Cant figure out where the problem is...

Comment: which editor are you using?

Comment: Im using intellij

Answer (score 0):

make sure you pip installed it, if the issue is still there, restart the editor. also, check if you have activated the environment in which you pip installed the module(if you are using anaconda)